# Error in creating libfftw3f-3.lib

Tags: fftw

I'm trying to create `.lib` files from `.def` files downloaded from FFTW.

According to [this instruction](http://fftw.org/install/windows.html), I should use `lib.exe` to create lib files.

[This screenshot](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0nWGRQ8M54icUdhazBZT1lDRUk/edit?usp=sharing) shows how I run the command and what error I get.

Answer (score 0):

Try running link.exe from the directory that contains the .lib file. You can use the full-path to link.exe if you don't have it in your path.